# Too many output arguments Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a small function that transforms degrees to radians. I would like to use this function within a script that transforms spherical geographical coordinates into sperical cartesian coordinates. I'm getting the `too many output argument`error whenever i pass coordinates to the function, can someone look at it and possibly show me where i'm messing up?

Function begins here:

```
 function [] = winkelradiant( w )
 dez = w(1) + w(2)/60 + w(3)/3600;
 rad = dez * (pi/180);
 rad
 end
```

Script begins here:

```
 function GB
 w1 = [8, 47, 15.2356];
 w2 = [45, 12, 46.1887];
 winkelradiant(w1)
 winkelradiant(w2)

 %Transform geographical to cartesian coordinates
 r = 6371000.785;
 a =[45, 12, 46.1887];
 b =[8, 47, 15.2356];
 phi = winkelradiant(a);
 lambda = winkelradiant(b);
 x = r*cos(phi)*cos(lambda);
 y = r*cos(phi)*sin(lambda);
 z = r*sin(phi);
 KO = [x y z]
```

Comment: Try function rad = winkelradiant( w ) in the first line

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you told me what that is supposed to do, or what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: ok, i think you have defined the function in wrong way. Maybe such a definition is possible, but i don't know what it is supposed to do. Here is info about functions in MATLAB http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Comment: `winkelradiant` does not return `rad`.  Change your `function` header to `function rad = winkelradient(w)`.

Comment: @freude - No you are correct.  No variables are returned in the function and that's why it isn't working.

Comment: As you might see there are variables y1...yN defining the output: [y1,...,yN] = myfun(x1,...,xM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your function definition has no return arguments.

Comment: Short and sexy, I like it!

Answer (score 4):

```
 function rad  = winkelradiant( w )
 dez = w(1) + w(2)/60 + w(3)/3600;
 rad = dez * (pi/180); 
 end
```

In matlab, return veriable(s) must be defined in first line of function. If there is only one variable to return then do like in above example. However if there are several return variables then it can be done using following approach:

```
function [vout1 vout2]  = functionxyz( vin )
 vout1 = vin *2 ;
 vout2 = vin + 2 ;
end
```

Comment: Instead of code dumping, **explain** why this works.  For a novice MATLAB user, they may not know what they did wrong so just showing them code probably won't help.